# Generalised hydrodynamics and the Dirac delta potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conservation-laws, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions, integrable-systems

Generalised Hydrodynamics is a theory of hydrodynamics for Quantum integrable systems. Those system are integrable in the sense that  one can find an infinite number of conserved charges i.e. operators $Q_i$ that commute with themselves and with the Hamiltonian, such that $$[Q_i,Q_j]=0, \quad [Q_i,H]=0.$$ If additionaly the conserved charge are local (they can be written as integral of local operators) $$Q_i=\int dx q_i(x)$$ then, Generalised Hydrodynamics is obtained from manipulation on the hierachy of conservation equations $$\partial_t q_i +\partial_x j_i=0$$ where $j_i$ is the current associated to the charge $q_i$

Now here is my problem, consider the case of noninteracting fermions in a repulsive Dirac delta potential with the one particle hamiltonian $$H=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_x^2 + c \delta(x).$$
I believe this system to be integrable however I cannot find the set of conserved charges. My question is the following, is there a method to find it?
How is this changed for an attractive potential, that is when $c$ is negative?

Comment: For a non-interacting problem surely the single particle Hamiltonians give you a set of conserved charges?

Comment: Hi @gab-ert. Welcome to Phys.SE. Where does the fermionic nature of the particles enter the model?